# apache2 - can I setup a subdomain without creating an A record?

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

So I have

```
mydomain.com
```

and I want

```
test.mydomain.com
```

Can I set this up without creating an A record for the subdomain? Either with .htaccess or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something in DNS. It can be an `A`, a `CNAME`, or you can use a wildcard entry like

```
*.mydomain.com.  IN  CNAME  mydomain.com.
```

The above is a wildcard record, which will match any name under `mydomain.com`. You can also use a record for your specific name.

```
; an alias name pointing to mydomain.com
test.mydomain.com.  IN  CNAME  mydomain.com.

; or, a regular DNS record
test.mydomain.com.  IN  A      1.2.3.4
```

Without a DNS entry, the browser will not know about your Apache instance to begin with. So you cannot solve this with `.htaccess` or Apache config alone, DNS must route the request to Apache first.

Comment: so the wildcard cname means I could setup multiple subdomains? site1.mydomain.com, site2.mydomain.com?

Comment: That's correct. I believe if you specifically add DNS for a subdomain, that would override the wildcard. The wildcard will match anything that is not otherwise defined in DNS.